# TwitterAPIExchange is not returning image relate urls for some tweets?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

This is the code I am using in my Programming. But the thing is for few Tweets I am able to get image URL related to the tweet, but for few tweets I am not getting specific Tweets related Image URL? I tried to use embeded tweet cards,because of that I am not getting tweets dynamically. I want something like dynamically along with images for all tweets using API

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "XXXXX",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "XXXXX",
'consumer_key' => "XXXXX",
'consumer_secret' => "XXXXX"
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

$requestMethod = "GET";

$getfield = '?screen_name=XXXXX&count=4';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$user_timeline = $twitter
         ->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest();

$user_timeline = json_decode($user_timeline);             


$result_string="[";
$count=0;
foreach($user_timeline as $upost)
{
$count++;
if (!isset($post)) 
$post = new stdClass();
$post->created_at =    $upost->created_at;
$post->id =    $upost->id_str ;
$post->text =    $upost->text ; 
$post->url ="";

$var = get_object_vars($upost->entities);


if (isset($var['media']))
{
    $post->url =    get_object_vars(get_object_vars($upost->entities)['media'][0])['media_url'] ;
}
else{
    $post->url ="";
} 
$result_string .=json_encode($post);
if($count < 4)
{
    $result_string .=",";
}
}
$result_string .="]";

echo $result_string;
```

Comment: Could you please share some examples of tweets which are not working?

Comment: isset($var['media']) is not comming for few tweets in the above code. So I'm setting it's URL empty in ELSE block of my code.

Comment: i.e $var['media'] is comming as empty for 3 tweets. And for another one tweet I'm getting $var['media'], so I'm able to get Tweet related image url. $getfield = '?screen_name=XXXXX&count=4'; Here I'm selecting only 4 tweets.

Comment: Are you sure those tweets have images? Could you share the Twitter ID of the tweet thatvis giving you problems?

Comment: Terence Eden@Thank you for your reply. Ex: URL""https://www.equitybulls.com/admin/news2006/news_det.asp?id=241798""
. I my case, I said 3 twitter related images are not comming, because they did not  uploaded and more over they copied some URL from some web site, and  pasting that URL in their tweet. So I'm not getting image.

Comment: So first I got ID's of twitter related tweets, and called twitter widget code. That's it, i got dynamic tweets in my website. 
Use full Links: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/overview
 AND
https://medium.com/@makerspirit/how-to-style-your-twitter-widget-styling-on-shadow-dom-a405c36edd10